# Connect mysqli without print error

Tags: php, mysqli, error-reporting

Is any way to call `new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db_name)` without printing the following errors?

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'user'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES) in...

I don't like to ignore errors (`@` or `error_reporting(0)`), i would like any other "better practice" way.

Comment: I don't understand.. you don't want to see an error saying your access to the database is denied?? A better practice would be to write the code so that no warning is printed

Comment: I would imagine that you are trying to check if a connection can be made, and if not, load the page another way instead, but the warning gets in the way. Am I correct?

Comment: +1 for "I don't like to ignore errors"

Comment: @3ventic That is a solution, check if the connection is possible before trying to connect, if possible then connect, if not get the error it would give (Ex.: Wrong password) and send it to my error handler. But never print it.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks i think it is a Best Practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you don't want errors to be printed - just tell PHP not to print them.
Configure PHP this way:

```
display_errors = 0
log_errors = 1
```

if you want to catch errors in some handler, [you have to register it first.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

Comment: I don't want to ignore every error, i use an ErrorHandler class, so if the password is wrong i will send the error "Wrong password" to my handler

Comment: Now i have a noob question for you: When i set "display_errors = 0" on my PHP configuration i can still handle them with my handler?

Comment: Yes, this is irrelevant matters.